# Open source video conferencing software with encryption

Tags: encryption, network, privacy, conference

A couple of friends and I are looking for an open source video conferencing software. We'd like to run the server on a Debian box, but the clients are Windows machines. Most importantly, it should support encrypted video calls. It would be very cool if it would also allow conference calls (i.e. more than two people have an encrypted video chat together).

Now, the open source criterion is mostly a measure of security to us. If we use video conferencing with encryption, we'd like to see the code that does the actual encryption.

We have tried to use freeswitch and MicroSIP but ran into serious problems. We then found [this very unsettling stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558493/does-freeswitch-support-video-conference) which basically says that this is at least going to be very tough.

We would have thought that this is something that *everyone* wants ever since PRISM, but we couldn't figure it out so far. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use Linphone for that. It supports Audio conference and Secure communications (TLS, SRTP, zRTP). See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34509/can-skype-chat-be-protected-from-snooping-are-there-safe-alternatives/67576#67576

Comment: Also, this project specifically makes recommendations in the wake of PRISM: https://prism-break.org/en/all/#video-voice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jitsi offers video chat, comes with OTR/SRTP/ZRTP.
https://jitsi.org/
The docs say that it can do multi-user video
https://jitsi.org/Projects/JitsiVideobridge

I have only tried the chat and phone function, they work very well